# Warning : Variable is passed by reference before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime

Tags: .net, vb.net, warnings, nullreferenceexception

I m working on vb.net and I get the above warning for unassigned reference variable. When I assign **Nothing** to the variable the warning disappears. Now my question is what difference does assigning a **Nothing** value makes to a reference variable ?? Even if I don't assign Nothing explicitly then also the default value is **Nothing** only i guess ?? correct me if i m wrong.

PS : This is what microsoft says "If a variable has never been assigned a value, it holds the default value for its data type. For a reference data type, that default value is Nothing." Here is the complete Link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc42030

Comment: It means you’ve assigned it a value and so the compiler check for whether you’ve assigned it a value or not doesn’t produce a warning. Well done. You’ve managed to make the warning go away and done nothing to prevent the problem it was trying to help stop you getting into. Good for you.

Comment: You don't show any example code, but it should be pointed out that defining function parameters as ByRef should *only* be done if the function will make an assignment to that parameter which needs to be passed back to the caller.  I see a lot of novice programmers assume that because a variable is a reference to an object, that the parameter must be ByRef.  That's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll notice that it is a warning and not an error.  There's nothing specifically wrong with the code, which is why it's not an error.  `ByRef` parameters are used to pass data into and out of methods though, so if you forgot to assign as a value before passing that variable as an argument, an `NullReferenceException` might be thrown in the method if it assumes that the parameter has a value.  By setting the variable to `Nothing` explicitly, you're telling the compiler that you specifically want the variable to be `Nothing` and it's not just that you forgot to assign some other value.